# How to Post JSON data and Zip File using web api?

Tags: angularjs, api, http-post

I created a angular project with export feature for able to download output as a .Zip to local computer.

Now, I plan to add a new feature to upload the zip file directly to the server using web API instead to download to local, is it possible on angular? I am thinking to modify my function for download to local and change it to push to external server (but not working).
 Since I am new with angular.

@floc Updated:

Thanks for the guide, so I am created the functions as follow:

```
private function zip($path, $id)
    {
        $realPath = realpath($path);
        $absolute = $realPath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $ignore   = array(realpath($this->exportsPath), $realPath);

        //delete old zip if it exists
        if (is_file($absolute.$id.'.zip')) {
            unlink($absolute.$id.'.zip');
        }

        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zip->open($absolute.$id.'.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);

        $files = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($realPath), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            $path = $file->getRealPath();

            if ( ! in_array($file->getRealPath(), $ignore)) {
                if (is_dir($file))
                {
                    $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($absolute, '', $path));              
                }
                else if (is_file($file))
                {
                    $zip->addFromString(str_replace($absolute, '', $path), file_get_contents($file));
                }
            }
        }

        if ($zip->close()) {
            return $absolute.$id.'.zip';
        }
    }
```

instead save as zip file I want to that zip file upload using web api in one click. I want to modified it but still no luck for this. :(

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Comment: Zip files don't translate to JSON well. It is best to post them as `application/zip` or `application/octet-stream`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do this with Angular.

## 1) Declare a new directive

You will need to define a new directive to bind your `<input type="file" />` with your controller.

```
.directive("fileArg", [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            fileArg: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            element.bind("change", function (changeEvent) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.fileArg = changeEvent.target.files[0];
                });
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Now, in your HTML :

```
<input type="file" file-arg="vm.zipFile" />
```

## 2) Send the file to your API

```
function importFile() {

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("data", $scope.zipFile);

    var options = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": undefined
        }
    };

    this.ohttp.post("yourApiUrl", formData, options).then(r => {

        if (r.data.Error) {
            // Do something
        }

        // Do something else

    });

}
```

## 3) Read the file in your API

Now, you need to read the file you've sent. For that, you will use the `MultipartFormDataMemoryStreamProvider`.

Like so.

```
[Route("yourApiUrl")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<dynamic> ImportZipFileAsync()
{
    try
    {
        model = await ReadZipFile();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return new { Error = true, Message = e.Message };
    }

    return "success";
}

private async Task ReadZipFile()
{
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataMemoryStreamProvider();

    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

    var file = provider.FileStreams.FirstOrDefault();

    if (file.Value != null)
    {
        var fileName = file.Key;
        var fileData = file.Value;

        if (!fileName.ToLowerInvariant().EndsWith(".zip"))
        {
            throw new FileLoadException("Wrong file type");
        }

        var data = new MemoryStream();
        fileData.CopyTo(data);
        var dataBytes = data.ToArray();

        // Do whatever you want with your dataBytes
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("file.Value");
    }
}
```